# How To give optional parameter in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi Everyone i am created one api, where i will use [city] as first parameter to get result based on city, but i need [id] also as second parameter but [id] is optional, same time we use [id] as second parameter  and  sometime not, please help me out

for ex-

1-get data based on city

url=127.0.0.1:8000/api/car/city

2-get data based on city and id

url= 127.0.0.1:8000/api/car/city/id

**serializers.py**

```
class CarNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model=CarModelNameSerializer()
    company=CarCompanySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['id','car_number','model','company']
```

**views.py**

```
class CarNumberViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class= CarNumberSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        params= kwargs
        params_list=params['pk']
        car=Car.objects.filter(city=params_list)
        serializer=CarNumberSerializer(car,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
routers.register(r'gms/car_list',CarNumberViewset)
```

Comment: can you please clarify this line "where i will city_id as parameter but i need id parameter "

Comment: @shivankgtm actually currently i am getting based on city but need one more parameter which is optional (id),means get data based on city and get data based on city and id

Comment: you are mentioning "city" but I can't see it anywhere in your code. can you add more details

Comment: "url= 127.0.0.1:8000/api/car/city/id" in this "id" is id of what? car or city? , also a proper way of having this filter should be query_params such as. ```/api/?car=car_id?city=city_id```

Comment: ```/api/car/city/city_id``` the literal meaning of this URL is to give me all cars details/list which is in the city whose id is city_id.

is it your usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def retreive(...)` is for getting a single `Car` object by primary-key.
For example `gms/car_list/1` will return the `Car` object with id 1.

Right now you have replaced the car's id with a city id.

I would use `list` method instead with [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

1. Install django-filter (check docs).
2. Replace with:

```
class CarNumberViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarNumberSerializer
    filterset_fields = ('city', 'id')
    
    # No need to overwrite list() or retrieve() here. DRF handles everything.
```

3. Now you can send a request to `/gms/car_list?city=4&id=1` to filter by `id` and `city`.